# Symfony Form not releasing memory

Tags: php, symfony, memory, memory-leaks, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony [Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) to validate data from an array in a loop.

For each item in the array, I create a form instance that trigger's a form submission.

After that, I check if the form is valid and then push the data to an array.

What I have noticed now is that for each run the memory usage increases by about 1 MB.
And PHP seems not to clear the old form instances.

My code looks like this:

```php
foreach ($dataToValidate as $item) {
    $form = $this->formFactory->create($formType, $item, ['csrf_protection' => false, 'allow_extra_fields' => false]);
    $form->submit($item);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && true === $form->isValid()) {
        $validData[] = $form->getData();
    }
}
```

I have tried things like this inside the foreach to clear the memory:

```php
$form = null;
unset($form);
gc_collect_cycles();
```

But somehow the memory usage is getting bigger and bigger with every form-validation.

I have tested it with about 200 items in the `$dataToValidate` array.

Before the validation the memory usage (returned by `memory_get_usage();`) is at around 10 MB. After validating the 200 items it goes up to over 70 MB.

**Edit**

As it was asked in the comments: The form type's I'm using are pretty basic and look for example like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the validator component directly?

Comment: @Laurenz Glück, I think you end up with TWO "long" arrays of Object. First → `$dataToValidate` and second -> `$validData` containing "validated" objects. So in theory **after** your loop you just could `unset($dataToValidate);`

Comment: @V-Light I actually already tried to unset the `$dataToValidate` array after the loop. But the huge amount of memory seems to come from the formFactory...

Comment: @LaurenzGlück, well you also could try to unset ($form) inside a loop after you "extracted" validated data. ```php $form->getData(); unset($form);``` But TBH it all looks like "hacks" trying to fight the symptoms rather than the cause. 
We need to know what object/entity is configured as 'data_class' in `configureOptions()` method of your form. If it's an entity, please inspect those in debug-bar. If the underlying entity is "heavy" then objects using this entity will also be "heavy"

Comment: @LaurenzGlück also consider using one Form with CollectionType instead of creating a bunch of standalone forms. 
P.S. Advice to use `symfony/validator` is also a good one. It looks like you "misuse" forms just for validation (your constraints in `buildForm()`)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it seems to me that it would be more correct to use the [`Validator Component`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html)

Here is an example of how this can be implemented, only in your case, your array needs to be turned into an object of one or another entity:

```
    $validator = Validation::createValidator();
    $entity = new YouEntity();
    $entity->setName('SOME_FIELD');
    //...
    $violations = $validator->validate($entity);
```

I specify rules mostly in entity in `@Assert` annotations

```
    class User
    {
        /**
         * @Assert\Length(min = 3)
         * @Assert\NotBlank
         */
        private $name;
    
        /**
         * @Assert\Email
         * @Assert\NotBlank
         */
        private $email;

       /**
        * @var string username
        *
        * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=50, unique=true, options={"comment":"username"})
        * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[0-9A-Za-z-]+$/")
        * @Assert\NotBlank()
        * @Assert\Length(
        *      min = 4,
        *      max = 50)
        */
       private $username;
       
       //...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Is there a way to use form type's with this validator?
Or how do you define the validation "rules"?

Comment: We use the Symfony Form based validation a lot in our application and have about 150 FormType's at the moment. So I'm wondering if there is a simple way to use this FormType's with the Validator Component?

Comment: @LaurenzGlück The form component uses the validation component.  The only issue is where the validation rules are defined.  If the rules are defined directly on the entities then you can use the validator component no problem.  If the form itself applies additional rules then you might have some work to do.  Perhaps you could update your question with a short code snippet showing one of your "form based validation" items.

Comment: @LaurenzGlück I changed my answer a bit, maybe it will help you)

Comment: I'm just wondering if the Symfony form component uses the validation component, will I then probably not have the same memory issue?

Comment: @Cerad I have just added a screenshot of one of my form types to the question. The items in the `$dataToValidate` array are just basic key / value arrays and no objects. 
In my current case they are coming from a CSV file which should be imported...
So I think going away from the Symfony forms to just the validator component will be not that easy.

Comment: @LaurenzGlück Yep.  Things are a bit bleak.  This is the first time I can remember someone looping on forms in order to validate.  Not surprised there are memory leaks and unfortunately the Form code is not meant to be read by humans.  All I can suggest is that you take one FormType that is causing problems, configure a pure validator for it and least verify that the memory issues go away.  PHP itself is not particularly well suited for bulk operations.

Comment: @Cerad That's an interesting input! I will try it in one case and see if this makes the memory issue go away.
If you say that you have never seen someone looping on forms - would it then maybe be better in may case to have one form type with a "sub-type" to validate all items at once?

Comment: @LaurenzGlück  I don't understand your "sub-type" proposal but if you are going to take the time to make changes then I would think you should try the "pure" validation approach first.  Symfony keeps changing their documentation layout.  This should get you started with [array validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html).  Though the example is overly complicated.

Comment: @LaurenzGlück You might also think about using entities.  You will need an extra step to convert your arrays to objects. But at then end of the day you will be able to use forms as well as bulk imports without duplicating the validation constraints.

Comment: @Cerad I have just tested the array validation using the Validator Component and the memory is not increasing. So this might be a good alternative.

Comment: @LaurenzGlück Good to hear.  At this point I would once again urge to make one more test using an object with validation on individual properties.  This should give you enough info to be able to make a wise decision on how to proceed.

Comment: @LaurenzGlück, if you're facing memory leak issue, call the reset method on your validator. Validators like TraceableValidator has a $this->collectedData array which keep growing. Call the $this->validator->reset(); to free up memory.